# D3 Angular confusion: fill color doesn't change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

Develop angular application with D3 JS and faced with the problem that I can not change fill color of svg.

If you look this code, you can see that I create one svg and trying to insert another one from my vendor:

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
        var svgContainer = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
                                             .attr("width", $window.screenX - 2*100)
                                             .attr("id", "oil-game")
                                             .attr("height", 1200);

        var well = svgContainer.append("g");
        angular.forEach(scope.d3WellDetails, function (value, key) {
            var circle = well.append("circle")
                                     .attr("cx", 55)
                                     .attr("cy", 100 + key*115)
                                     .attr("r", 40)
                                     .attr('stroke', '#0897c7')
                                     .attr('stroke-width', '5')
                                     .attr('fill', 'white');
            well.append("text")
                .attr('x', 50)
                .attr('y', 85 + key*115)
                .attr('fill', '#0897c7')
                .attr('font-size', 16)
                .attr('font-weight', 900)
                .text(value.Name);
            well.append('svg:image')
                .attr('xlink:href', '../../images/wells.svg')
                .attr('x', 40)
                .attr('y', 95 + key*115)
                .attr("width", 30)
                .attr("height", 30)
                .attr('fill', '#0897c7');
        });
}
```

I want you to look to the final part when I'm appending new svg. If I'm using `.attr('xlink:href', '//')` I can't change fill color of svg.

But if I use `.attr('src', '//')` I don't see svg image but at developer tool I can see it as empty.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you asking to change the fill attribute in the imported svg (../../images/wells.svg)...i don't think its possible like the way you doing.  however one way would be to do an ajax to get the wells.svg and then add the fill style attribute in well.svg then append it..

Comment: @Cyril the point is I can not change fill of impoting svg neither with css nor through directive. Fill changes only if I set attribute `fill="#color"` in svg. Is it an expected behavior? I don't think so. Maybe I mistaked when I put svg at directive?

Comment: You cannot change the colour of an `<image>`

Comment: @Robert Longson can you write an example of code that I could do it? or if I make `<svg>` how can I change fill color?

Comment: Edit wells.svg with a text editor to have the colour you want, or write code to generate all of wells.svg's markup inline in your current file.

Comment: @Robert Longson it's not working. I tried to implement svg code through attribute, and I could changed fill, but there is no way to change width and height, size and etc.. So I see only one way now - create two different icons and change them onclick.

Comment: You could use a transform or a viewBox to change the width, height and size.Two icons is probably simplest though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case doesn't have to do with Angular, but rather with the way you're appending the external SVG as an image.

Instead I would suggest you append the external SVG as an SVG Definition and include it with the 'use' attribute. This will allow you to style the imported SVG after the fact. Keep in mind that inline styles in the definition will override styles added with js or css after the fact.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/3fx1553f/

HTML:

```
<svg id="svg-defs" version="1.1" style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <g id="gdef1">
      <circle id="s1" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fill-red {
  fill: red;
}
```

JS:

```
var svg = d3.select('#container')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'main')
  .attr('width', '540px')
  .attr('height', '540px');

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class','fill-red')
  .append('use')
  .attr('xlink:href', '#gdef1');
```